# SQL Azure is slow

Tags: sql-server, azure, iis, virtual-machine, azure-sql-database

We have a website up and running, and we decided to move to Azure.
The database was migrated to SQL Azure using the DMA (Data Migration Assistant), and we created a VM on Azure, then we published the website on IIS on the VM.
Now, we have two different domains with two different databases, and the old website is much faster than the new one (azure website).
We couldn't find exactly where is the bottleneck; in the database, or in the connection, or in the VM (processor or IIS, ...).

The specifications of the Azure resources:

- VM: Standard D2s v3 (2 vcpus, 8 GB memory)
- DB: Premium P1: 125 DTUs

Can anyone hint us how to detect the main cause of this slowness?

Comment: Your website hosting server and your database server are the same?

Comment: Yeah, they are on the same server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application have load then the best practice to do that host your application on a different azure machine and host your database on a different azure server and make a virtual network between your machines.

> When you create an Azure virtual machine (VM), you must create a
>   virtual network (VNet) or use an existing VNet. You also need to
>   decide how your VMs are intended to be accessed on the VNet. It is
>   important to plan before creating resources and make sure that you
>   understand the limits of networking resources.

### Load balancers

> Azure Load Balancer delivers high availability and
>   network performance to your applications. A load balancer can be
>   configured to balance incoming Internet traffic to VMs or balance
>   traffic between VMs in a VNet. A load balancer can also balance
>   traffic between on-premises computers and VMs in a cross-premises
>   network, or forward external traffic to a specific VM.
>
> The load balancer maps incoming and outgoing traffic between the
>   public IP address and port on the load balancer and the private IP
>   address and port of the VM.

Read  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/network-overview) to configure.